# ANDROID open source lib to do graphics in real time

Tags: android, graph, charts

i need lib to do simple graphics how scatter chart.
I need to draw graphics using real time date. At example( i read every 10 sec a data, and i want to insert this data in the graphics in real time). is there some open source lib that i can use in my application project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try AChartEngine. Download the library and the demo code from [here](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/), see the website [here](http://www.achartengine.org) and search on youtube for some awesome video tutorials.

Comment: whit this lib is possible to insert in real time tha data ?

Comment: Yes, you keep adding data to the dataset and call repaint on the chart view.